# Testing Rails Shopify App with Capybara & Cucumber (upgrading Shopify plan in test causes authentication error)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, shopify

I have a Shopify Rails app and I am trying to test some of the functionality of my "pro" plan, but having trouble updating the test shop plan. I can login no problem, but when I try to update my shops plan via capybara, I get redirected to the login page.

I've done some troubleshooting, but I really have no idea where this issue is stemming from because it works fine when I try it manually in my browser. Maybe database_cleaner or caching issue?

Here's my cucumber steps (basically just login to the app, choose a plan):

```
Background:
    Given I am a logged in user
    When I am on the pro plan
```

Capybara:

```
When "I am a logged in user" do
  step "I visit the login page"
  step "I supply my shopify url"
  step "I get taken to the app index page"
end

When /^I am on the (.+) plan$/ do |plan|
  click_link_or_button "Settings & Notifications"
  click_link_or_button "edit plan"
  choose("shop_plan_#{plan}")
  click_link_or_button "Update Plan"
  click_link_or_button "Approve charge"
end
```

The driver successfully authenticates into the app, visits the edit plan page, visits the Shopify "approve charge" authorization page. But after clicking "approve charge", the browser is redirected to the login page instead of the action I am expecting.

When I try this manually in my own browser, I am redirected to the correct page.

Here's the actual controller action when a user updates their plan:

Step 1. User selects plan from settings page - posts to this action, which will redirect user to a page with embedded JS which redirects user to a Shopify authentication page (has to be done this way to escape the embedded app iframe).

```
def update_plan_step_1
    @plan = shop_params[:plan]
    redirect_url = current_shop.confirm_plan(@plan)
    gon.authorization_url = redirect_url
    render :redirect_to_shopify_auth
end
```

And here is the confirm_plan method. Basically this creates a new Shopify Charge object - Shopify is going to respond with a unique expiring URL for the user to confirm the charge. We need to provide the price, name, and return_url for Shopify to redirect the user after they approve the charge:

```
def confirm_plan(shopify_plan)
    price = Plan.cost(shopify_plan)
    name = shopify_plan + "Plan"
    return_url = update_plan_step_2_url(:host => Figaro.env.root_uri)
    response = ShopifyAPI::RecurringApplicationCharge.create({
                              :name => name, 
                              :price => price, 
                              :return_url => return_url, 
                              :test=> !Rails.env.production? 
                              })
     response.confirmation_url
 end
```

When I pry into this, I can see the return_url is set to the proper location: `http://localhost:23456/shop/plans/update_plan_step_2` (shops#update_plan_step_2).

After user approves the charge on Shopify authentication page, they are supposed to be redirected to this action:

```
def update_plan_step_2
    #some code to update our shop record
end
```

But when I pry into this action, I can see that it's not even being called in the Test, so I know the issue is happening before this.

To summarize, it looks like everything is working until the user is supposed  to be redirected to `http://localhost:23456/shop/plans/update_plan_step_2`. Instead, they are redirected to the authentication page.

Why would this happen in the test, but not when I try doing it manually? Any ideas on where the issue lies?

Logs:

```
Started GET "/shop/plans/update_plan_step_2?charge_id=12345" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-10-30 11:09:58 -0700
Processing by ShopsController#update_plan_step_2 as HTML
Parameters: {"charge_id"=>"12345"}
Redirected to http://localhost:23456/login
```

So we can see user is being redirected to authenticate. Why would this be happening only in test? Could it be a caching issue where the shop session is not being stored in the test? And the session is destroyed when the user is taken off the app to the Shopify authentication page?

EDIT: I know exactly where it's being redirected (in an before action in the controller)

```
def shopify_session
      if shop_session
        begin
          ShopifyAPI::Base.activate_session(shop_session)
          yield
        ensure
          ShopifyAPI::Base.clear_session
        end
      else
        redirect_to_login  ## REDIRECTED HERE
      end
    end
```

Which means after user authenticates via Shopify, the shopify_session no longer exists.

Comment: What driver are you using in Capybara?

Comment: Hi @TomWalpole, sorry for the late response. Here is my config: Capybara.register_driver :chrome do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome)
end
Capybara.javascript_driver = :chrome

Comment: are your scenarios tagged with @javascript?

Comment: I have the tag at the top of my feature: @javascript
Feature: User adds a customer

Comment: I thought that was a DRY way to do it, but does it need to be above each scenario?

Comment: It should work on the feature -  hmmm -- have you tried looking at your test log to see whats happening with the requests?

Comment: Just checked my test.log and it's completely blank.. Looking into that now

Comment: I can see this in the console: "Started GET "/shop/plans/update_plan_step_2?charge_id=12345" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-10-30 11:09:58 -0700
Processing by ShopsController#update_plan_step_2 as HTML
  Parameters: {"charge_id"=>"12345"}
Redirected to http://localhost:23456/login".  So for some reason user is being redirected to login page

Comment: Could it be a caching issue where the shop session is not being stored in the test? And the session is destroyed when the user is taken off the app to the Shopify authentication page?

Comment: So from the logs it looks like the user is being redirected to update_plan_step_2 and then that (or a before action) is redirecting to login -- what is update_plan_step_2 doing - and what before_actions are used with it?

Comment: OH -- it could be that you're redirecting to localhost but the initial login is going to 127.0.0.1 -- that could mean session cookies set become invalid

Comment: I'll look into that now. Also, when I pry into update_plan_step_2 it does not even get called. here is the before action on the entire controller --> def login_again_if_different_shop
    if shop_session && params[:shop] && params[:shop].is_a?(String) && shop_session.url != params[:shop]
      redirect_to login_path(shop: params[:shop])
    end
  end

Comment: The action not being called would imply its getting stopped in the before_action -- so you could pry that and see whats making it redirect to the login_path

Comment: Interesting.. I found where it's being redirected: def shopify_session
      if shop_session
        begin
          ShopifyAPI::Base.activate_session(shop_session)
          yield
        ensure
          ShopifyAPI::Base.clear_session
        end
      else
        redirect_to_login  ### REDIRECTED FROM HERE
      end
    end

Comment: ok - so it sounds like you don't actually have a shop_session, make sure the hostnames are all the same so the session cookies are correctly being used - You could try setting Capybara.default_host = 'localhost' as a quick check without having to change all the redirect urls

Comment: But the shop_session exists in every action prior to the user being taken off the page to Shopify authentication, then the shop_session gets lost

Comment: its lost when it redirects back -- which has the hostname of 'localhost' all prior interactions probably have a hostname of '127.0.0.1' which would mean the session cookies from '127.0.0.1' are not valid on 'localhost'

Comment: Ahhh I understand now! That did it, I just swapped my figaro root_url to 127.0.0.1 and it's fixed! Thank you so much! If you want to leave an answer I will accept :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Capybara.default_host` defaults to 127.0.0.1 which means that all access to your app occurs over http://127.0.0.1/some/path by default when visiting paths in your app with Capybara.  When your app redirects to http://localhost/some/path the session cookies stored for the hostname 127.0.0.1 are not valid for hostname localhost so the app redirects to login.  Either change your return_url to use a hostname of 127.0.0.1 or change `Capybara.default_host` to 'localhost' (using 'localhost' for default_host has a few small gotchas when using selenium though, so better to change the return_url)

Comment: thanks again for all your help. bounty will be rewarded as soon as I can give it

Comment: Glad I could be of assistance